# Weblogic - Ignore datasource error at startup

Tags: weblogic, datasource, startup

Can we configure datasources in weblogic 10 such that any error from that datasource does not stop starting the server in RUNNING mode? As of now when the datasource fails, the server starts in Admin mode.

I know I can do Resume from admin console in such situation. But I would want it to be autmoatic.

My application does not need that datasource to be up. It will impact only a specific module if this datasource fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the initial number of connection to open as 0 then it will skip the datasource at startup. It will create connection when your application module demands it at runtime.